# Check if an array is descending, ascending or not sorted?

Tags: javascript

I'm just beginning with programming using javascript and I need to practice some questions to get EXP with the logic of code build.
I got this question for homework but I can't make it work for some reason, even though it seems "logic" to me.
Check if an array is descending, ascending or not sorted using loops.

I'm just a noob so please try and help me figure this out as I only got to loops in my studies (:
 this is the code I wrote:

```
        var array = [1, 2, 3, 7 ];
        var d = 0;
        var c =0 ;
        var b = 1;
        var a = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= array.length; i++)
            {
                if (array[c]<array[b] && a!== -1  ){
                   d = -1;
                   c =c+1;
                   b = b+1;
                   if(c==array.length){
                    console.log("asc");
                     break;
                   }else{
                     continue;
                }

                } else if (array[c]>array[b] && d!==-1 ){
                           a = -1;
                           d= d+1;
                           b = b+1;
                    if(i=array.length){
                    console.log("dsc");
                    break;
               }else{continue;}

               } else{

                    console.log("unsorted array");
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: FWIW, arrays in JavaScript are 0-index based.

Comment: is `[1, 1]` ascending? what is `[42]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Check if an array is descending, ascending or not sorted using loops"

```js
// define the array
var array = [1,2,3,7];

// keep track of things
var isDescending = true;
var isAscending = true;

// we're looking ahead; loop from the first element to one before the last element
for (var i=0, l=array.length-1; i<l; i++)
{

   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   // log to the console to show what's happening for each loop iteration

   // this is the ith iteration 
   console.log("loop iteration %s", i);

   // breaking isDescending down:
   // is this value greater than the next value?
   console.log("A: (%s > %s) = %s", array[i], array[i+1], (array[i] > array[i+1]));

   // have all values been descending so far?
   console.log("B: isDescending: %s", isDescending);

   // if this value is greater than the next and all values have been descending so far, isDescending remains true. Otherwise, it's set to false.
  console.log("are A and B both true? %s", (isDescending && (array[i] > array[i+1])));

   // add a line break for clarity
   console.log("");

   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   // true if this is greater than the next and all other so far have been true
   isDescending = isDescending && (array[i] > array[i+1]);

   // true if this is less than the next and all others so far have been true
   isAscending = isAscending && (array[i] < array[i+1]);

}

if (isAscending)
{
  console.log('Ascending');
}
else if (isDescending) 
{
  console.log('Descending');
}
else
{
  console.log('Not Sorted');
}
```

Comment: ok, this looks close to something I could understand. it doesn't have functions so that's great for me.
can you try and explain this code line? what is happening here?
" isDescending = isDescending && (array[i] > array[i+1]);
   isAscending = isAscending && (array[i] < array[i+1]);"

Comment: Sure, first we set `isDesdending` is set to `true` with `var isDescending = true;`. For each iteration of the loop, check if the value at this array index, `array[i]` is greater than the next value, `array[i+i]`. If it is, `(array[i] > array[i+i]`) is `true`. Now we have `isDescending = (true && true)`, so `isDescending = true`.  If it's not true, we have `isDescending = (true && false)` so `isDescending = false`. If `isDescending` stays true after iterating through the entire array, the array is sorted in descending order.

Comment: wow, this blows me away. very simple and elegant! you just opened my mind to some new type of algorithm thinking.

Answer (score 30):

[`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) passes its predicate an index, which you can use to get an element’s predecessor:

```
function isAscending(arr) {
    return arr.every(function (x, i) {
        return i === 0 || x >= arr[i - 1];
    });
}
```

Here, we’re checking that every item (`x`) is greater than or equal to the item before it (`arr[i - 1]`) or has no item before it (`i === 0`).

Flip `>=` to `<=` for `isDescending`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a question that requires some sort of loop, with several `if` statements because there are several cases you need to tackle:

1. Array is empty or has only one element.
2. All items in the array are equal
3. Array is ascending - delta between 2 elements > 0, but some deltas may be 0
4. Array is descending - delta between 2 elements < 0, but some deltas may be 0
5. Not sorted - some deltas are > 0, and some are < 0

Depending on how the *sorted* is defined in the question, cases 1 & 2 might be regarded as *unsorted* as well.

```js
function findSortOrder(arr) {
  if(arr.length < 2) { // case 1
    return 'not enough items'; // can also be 'unsorted'
  }
  
  var ascending = null;
  var nextArr = arr.slice(1); // create an array that starts from the 2nd element of the original array

  for(var i = 0; i < nextArr.length; i++) {
    if (nextArr[i] === arr[i]) { // neutral - do nothing
    } else if(ascending === null) { // define the the direction by the 1st delta encountered
      ascending = nextArr[i] > arr[i];
    } else if (ascending !== nextArr[i] > arr[i]) { // case 5
      return 'unsorted';
    }
  }
  
  if(ascending === null) { // case 2
    return 'all items are equal'; // can also be 'unsorted'
  }
  
  return ascending ? 'ascending' : 'descending'; // cases 3 & 4
}

console.log(findSortOrder([1])); // case 1

console.log(findSortOrder([1, 1, 1, 1])); // case 2

console.log(findSortOrder([1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 7])); // case 3

console.log(findSortOrder([7, 2, 2, 1])); // case 4

console.log(findSortOrder([7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])); // case 5
```

Comment: Why `nextArr[i] - arr[i] === 0` instead of `nextArr[i] === arr[i]`? Likewise for `>`.

Comment: @Ryan - I was in a "deltas" frame of mind :) I've updated the code with you suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
function isAscending(arr) { 
  return arr
    .slice(1)
    .every((num,i) => num >= arr[i]); 
}

console.log(isAscending([1,2,3])); // true
console.log(isAscending([12,38,25])); // false
console.log(isAscending([103,398,52,629])); // false
```

1. arr.slice(1) --> allows us to start iteration at index 1 instead of 0
2. we'll iterate over "arr" with "every" & compare the current "num" against the previous "num" with "arr[i]"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a copy from the second element and check the predecessor for the wanted sort order.

```js
function checkArray(array) {
    var aa = array.slice(1);
    if (!aa.length) {
        return "Just one element";
    }
    if (aa.every((a, i) => array[i] > a)) {
        return "Ascending";
    }
    if (aa.every((a, i) => array[i] < a)) {
        return "Descending";
    }
    return "Unsorted";
}

console.log(checkArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(checkArray([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(checkArray([3, 1, 4, 2, 5]));
console.log(checkArray([42]));
```

Comment: Shouldnt this condition `if (aa.every((a, i) => array[i] > a))` return `Descending` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function isAscending(arr = []) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] <= arr[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general version (with typescript types) you could use:

```
export function isSorted<T>(
    arr: T[],
    compare: (a: T, b: T) => number = ((a: number, b: number) => a - b) as any
): boolean {
    return arr.every((x, i) => i == 0 || compare(arr[i - 1], x) <= 0);
}
```

Which you can use to check arrays of different data types, e.g.,

```
isSorted([1,2,3])
isSorted(["a","b","c"], (a,b) => a.localeCompare(b))
```

or even

```
class CustomType {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {}
}
function compareCustomType(a: CustomType, b: CustomType): number {
    return a.x - b.x || a.y - b.y;
}
isSorted([new CustomType(1, 2), new CustomType(1, 3)], compareCustomType);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually we may do even more by creating an Array method like `natureOf` which can tell us more about the nature of the array than just ascending, descendig or flat. `Array.natureOf()` shall give us a value between -1 and 1. If it is -1 the array is fully descending and 1 would mean fully ascending of course. Any value inbetween would give us the inclination of the array. As you would guess 0 would mean totally random or flat. (it's fairly easy to insert the logic to distinguish random from flat if that's also needed)

```js
Array.natureOf = function(a){
                   var nature = a.reduce((n,e,i,a) => i && a[i-1] !== e ? a[i-1] < e ? (n.asc++, n)
                                                                                     : (n.dsc++, n)
                                                                        : n, {asc:0, dsc:0});
                   return (nature.asc - nature.dsc) / (a.length-1);
                 };
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,7,11,13,14,15],
    brr = Array.from({length:2000000}, _ => ~~(Math.random()*1000000000));

console.log(`The nature of "arr" array is ${Array.natureOf(arr)}`);
console.log(`The nature of "brr" array is ${Array.natureOf(brr)}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  console.log(checkSort([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]));
  console.log(checkSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]));
  console.log(checkSort([2, 5, 8, 9, 4, 6]));

  function checkSort(arr){

    var isDescending, isAscending;
    isDescending = isAscending = true;

    const len = arr.length - 1;

    for (var index = 0 ; index < len ; index++){
      if(isAscending)
      isAscending = arr[index] <= arr[index + 1];// '<=' so as to check for same elements

      if(isDescending)
      isDescending = arr[index] >= arr[index + 1];//'<=' so as to check for same elements
    }

    var result = "Array is ";
    
    if (isAscending)
    return result.concat("sorted in ascending order");
    
    if (isDescending)
    return result.concat("sorted in descending order");
    
    return result.concat("not sorted");
```

Answer (score -3):

1. const isAscending=(arr)=>{
   for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   if(arr[i+1]<arr[i]){  return false } } return true }