# How to check sorting of array from high to low?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I check if an array of numbers e.g

const number = ['15','14','11','5'] is sorted from high to low in js
note: array could also be in invalid order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an array is descending, ascending or not sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990699/check-if-an-array-is-descending-ascending-or-not-sorted)

Comment: First element has to be bigger than second element. Second element has to be bigger than third element, ...

Comment: Descending: `number.slice(1).every((a,i) => +a <= +number[i])` - returns true if descending, otherwise false; ascending: `number.slice(1).every((a,i) => +a >= +number[i])` - returns true if ascending, otherwise false.

Comment: what if there is a duplicated number 
[1,2,3,3,4,5]